How to return a list of objects with an additional attribute that depends on the relationship between two tables
In the Backend in Java 17, Spring Boot, RDS for MySQL, I have an HR system, there is a Student and Recruiter entity, there is a feature that allows the Recruiter to favorite Students, and see the list of favorite Students. There is a Recruiter login system, and to search the list of all Students you need a Recruiter token.
The problem is the following, the front-end needs that when searching for all Students it returns jsons StudentResponse objects with an attribute that identifies whether it was favorited by Recruiter or not, for example a boolean attribute favorited = true(if it was favorited) or false( if it has not been favorited).
I managed to achieve this by doing some logic in Java, but it takes 55 seconds to return the json at the endpoint.
I need all of this to be faster but I don't know if a SQL query could do this and I don't know what else can solve it.
MySQL version: 8.0.35
Fiddle DB Link: https://dbfiddle.uk/7mcOWQR8
GitHub Repository: https://github.com/eduardozamit/plataforma-do-dale-api
Branch Most Updated: auth
I need that the response been an Student with an aditional attribute named favorited(boolean), like this the response will be:
id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
age INT,
recruiter_id BIGINT,
profile_picture VARCHAR(1000),
biography VARCHAR(2000),
favorited boolean

in the case in Java will be:
 public class StudentResponse {
       private long id;
       private int age;
       private String biography;
       private String profilePicture;
       private boolean favorited;

the repository of Recruiter:
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT s.id," +
            " s.age," +
            " s.gc_trail," +
            " s.biography," +
            " s.profile_picture," +
            " IF(rs.recruiter_id IS NULL, false, true) AS favorited" +
            " FROM student AS s" +
            " LEFT OUTER JOIN recruiter_student AS rs" +
            " ON s.id = rs.student_id;", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<StudentResponseDTO> findAllStudents(@Param("recruiter_id") Long id);

I tried using this query but it didn't work
The problem is simple, I just need to return all students with an attribute that adds "favorite" which will depend on whether they are favorited by the recruiter who is making the request.

Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. I understand that you have a question about doing a task more efficiently in SQL, but you haven't described enough to make it easy to answer. If you expand your question with an example of the CREATE TABLE statement, and a modest sample of data in that table, and show a mock-up of the result you want to get from the SQL statement, it will make it easier for  folks to help you.

Ideally share it on https://dbfiddle.uk/ so if anyone wants to test, they can do that without having to type in your code. I.e. please do not use screenshot images.

Also be specific about the version of RDS for MySQL you are using, because the best answer might depend on features in the latest release. Run the query SELECT VERSION(); to find out the relevant version.

I edited the question and added more details, thank you very much for the feedback!

Here's a solution:
SELECT DISTINCT s.id, s.age, s.biography, s.profilePicture,
  IF(rs.recruiter_id IS NULL, false, true) AS favorited
FROM student AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN recruiter_student AS rs
  ON s.id = rs.student_id;

Because of using OUTER JOIN, the row from student will be included in the result even if there is no match in the joined table.
If there is no match in recruiter_student, then the columns from that table may still be referenced, but their values are all NULL. In that case, the expression for favorited returns false.

P.S.: Not related to your question, but you will find that storing age is usually not a good idea, because the values will be incorrect soon. It's better to store birthdate and then calculate TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, CURRENT_DATE) AS age

I haven't studied how to do the age issue yet, but I already knew it was wrong, the intention of this api is to make an MVP, so I'll improve a lot of points.
Regarding the solution, I don't know if I implemented it incorrectly, but I was not successful using this query in RecruiterRepository, I had not given this information before, so I edited the question.
